# Show internal progress of Get-WMIObject

Tags: powershell, progress, get-wmiobject

I'm using `Get-WMIObject`, which can take quite a long time, depending on what exactly I want to get.
Sadly this doesn't show its progress by default.

Is there a way to get the actual internal progress of `Get-WMIObject`? (e.g. the percentage so one can calculate the expected time it will take)

Or is it just impossible to predict the duration of the execution?

Have not found anything in the web about it.

Comment: You mean if you run `Get-WmiObject` against multiple computers? Otherwise there's not much progress to track...

Comment: No, just one single Get-WmiObject command against one single computer.
For example Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product may take some time, which i would like to track.
So my guess was right, that this is impossible?

Comment: `Win32_Product` is well known long time task, if you just need list of installed apps, try using registry at `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`

Comment: Thanks for your anwer, but Win32_Product was just an example.
My final script will have several querys. 
So if i can't track the internal progress of them, i will just track how many querrys have already been executed in a progressbar.

Comment: @jemandanders That's the best you can do - `Get-WmiObject` basically just wraps a call to a WMI provider which won't in itself provide any progress-like information